# Warning when using saved Word2Vec model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, anaconda, nlp

## this warning appear when running this code

```
model.save('raw_gutenberg_model.w2v')
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('raw_gutenberg_model.w2v')
model['dog']
```

the error:

```
"/home/computer_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `doesnt_match` (Method will be removed in 4.0.0, use self.wv.doesnt_match() instead).
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel."
```

Comment: This is just a warning, not an error. Nothing to answer here.

Comment: yah i know it's warning and i mentioned this i just want to know why this warning appear

Answer (score 0):

This warning appears because the function specified will be deprecated in future versions of `gensim` and the authors wanted that to be clear to users.

You can disable these warnings using:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```